# Python - Create a loop to alter api search results and write to JSON/CSV

Tags: python, json, csv

I am completely lost on how to approach my problem. So far, I can write to a JSON file with one request inside my 'target_id'. The API will automatically output JSON.

The problem is, if I have a list of target_id's (currently in JSON and CSV), how can I loop it to alter the target_id's (aka alter the API URL) and then write to the same file?

Code:

```
import urllib.parse
import requests
import json

main_api = 'http://sc-api.com/?api_source=live&system=accounts&action=full_profile&'

target_id = 'abc'

url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({'target_id': target_id})
json_data = requests.get(url).json()
json_status = json_data['request_stats']['query_status']

#-----did the API work?-----
#print('API Status: ' + json_status)
#print()
#print(json_data)
#print()

handle = json_data['data']['handle']
moniker = json_data['data']['moniker']
citizen_number = json_data['data']['citizen_number']

#-----preview if no need to write to file-----
#print('target_id: ' + handle + ',', 'Moniker: ' + moniker + ',', 'Citizen Number: ' + citizen_number)

with open('new_test.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump((handle, moniker, citizen_number), f)
```

Here's the format of the file that contains a list of target IDs:

```
 [
      {
        "Handle": "name1"
      },
      {
        "Handle": "name2"
      },
      {
        "Handle": "name3"
      },
      {
        "Handle": "name4"
      },
      {
        "Handle": "name5"
      }
    ]
```

Any help on this or where to go with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Could you show what is the format of the file (JSON or CSV) containing the target_ids?

Comment: @DanielMesejo see the edited question. Thanks

Comment: @DanielMesejo quick follow up - i want to add time.sleep(10) between the search as hitting the api too frequently might cause issues. Where can i integrate this?

Comment: do it inside the loop before or after the call to requests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop on the file like using something like this:

```
import urllib.parse
import requests
import json

main_api = 'http://sc-api.com/?api_source=live&system=accounts&action=full_profile&'

with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    result = []
    for element in data:
        target_id = element['Handle']

        url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({'target_id': target_id})
        json_data = requests.get(url).json()
        json_status = json_data['request_stats']['query_status']

        handle = json_data['data']['handle']
        moniker = json_data['data']['moniker']
        citizen_number = json_data['data']['citizen_number']

        # -----preview if no need to write to file-----
        print('target_id: ' + handle + ',', 'Moniker: ' + moniker + ',', 'Citizen Number: ' + citizen_number)

        result.append({'target_id': handle, 'Moniker': moniker, 'Citizen Number': citizen_number})

    with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(result, f)
```

**Output**

```
target_id: abc, Moniker: C4sher, Citizen Number: 210602
target_id: abc, Moniker: C4sher, Citizen Number: 210602
target_id: abc, Moniker: C4sher, Citizen Number: 210602
target_id: abc, Moniker: C4sher, Citizen Number: 210602
target_id: abc, Moniker: C4sher, Citizen Number: 210602
```

Besides the above output this script creates a `'output.json'` with the following format:

```
[{"Moniker": "C4sher", "target_id": "abc", "Citizen Number": "210602"}, 
  {"Moniker": "C4sher", "target_id": "abc", "Citizen Number": "210602"}, 
  {"Moniker": "C4sher", "target_id": "abc", "Citizen Number": "210602"}, 
  {"Moniker": "C4sher", "target_id": "abc", "Citizen Number": "210602"}, 
  {"Moniker": "C4sher", "target_id": "abc", "Citizen Number": "210602"}]
```

**Some notes:**

The script assumes the `.py` file and the `'data.json'` file are in the same directory. Also it that the input file is named `'data.json'`. I change the example JSON of the question with a "working example" like this:

```
[
  {
    "Handle": "abc"
  },
  {
    "Handle": "abc"
  },
  {
    "Handle": "abc"
  },
  {
    "Handle": "abc"
  },
  {
    "Handle": "abc"
  }
]
```

Comment: You are a saviour! My sample json pasted wierdly but the way you wrote it is the way it is in a file. Many thanks. Just one question. For 5 queries it takes 11 seconds, and I've noticed it's because of the import json. If i manually query without writing to a file, it takes under a second (i.e. just printing, not exporting and therefore no need to import json). Any ideas why?

Comment: Perhaps the writing of the json? That is my best shot!